# MySQL get text substring between two paragraph tags

Tags: mysql, substring

I need to get a the first paragraph of a row entry. How can I do this through a query

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration of using the [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to return the first paragraph of a block of text, assuming a paragraph is delimited by a newline.

```
mysql> create table t (t text);

mysql> insert into t (t) values ('now is the time\nfor all good men');

mysql> select * from t;
+----------------------------------+
| t                                |
+----------------------------------+
| now is the time
for all good men |
+----------------------------------+

mysql> select substring_index(t, '\n', 1) from t;
+-----------------------------+
| substring_index(t, '\n', 1) |
+-----------------------------+
| now is the time             |
+-----------------------------+
```